# Multiple API models to C#

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core-2.1

I have an API controller which is calling a 3rd party API, and then deserializing it via two API models to C#. I am using JsonObject and JsonProperties in the API models.

Now I need to gather properties from both models in my response to the client. In the controller I have created two C# objects, each one getting info from the API models. I want to create a object holding specific properties from both objects. Can anyone advise on the best practice to accomplish this?

```
var personJson = await personResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
var companyJson = await companyResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

var UserObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Person.RootObject>(personJson);
var CompanyObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Company.RootObject>(companyJson);
```

Comment: Make a third model that is an amalgamation of the two data models.  This is usually called a viewmodel in an MVC context, since you are using Web.API think of it like _your API's model_

Comment: Which two objects are you indicating here in your code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a `class` for the data that you need to return and fill it, but in many cases it suffices to use an anonymous object which the framework will then serialize for you. Example:

```
return new
{
    UserId = UserObject.Id,
    UserFullname = UserObject.FirstName + " " + UserObject.LastName,
    CompanyId = CompanyObject.Id,
    CompanyName = CompanyObject.Name
};
```

You can take this as far as you need, even including arrays, dictionaries, lists, nested (sub)objects, etc.

Comment: thank you peter, this seems to be what i was looking for! if i wanted to make a class to hold the specific data, how would I specify which model(Company or User in my case) to gather data from? I am using [JsonObject] and [JsonProperty] in the Company and User-models